# EPiServer YSOD When trying to change model used in view

Tags: model-view-controller, model, episerver

Please could someone help with an problem that's blocking me. I've created a new Model for one of my views and I keep getting YSOD "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type X but this dictionary requires a model item of type Y" screen shot attached. I've done a lot of googleing and all I seem to find is suggestions to check the model the view is expecting. The View is expecting my new model I can't see any reason for this problem. I'm fairly new to EPiServer any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.
[image: YSOD Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually passing a view model implementing **IPageViewModel**, where T is a **RsaBasePageType**.

Is **ArticlesLandingLightModel** implementing that interface?

Comment: Hi Ted, Thanks for your reply. Do you know what restricts the model to requiring IPagevieModel. I am trying to remove the long chain of inheritance from the original model. I've not been able to find where the interface requirement is/

Comment: That comes from the view being rendered - it specifies its required model type through the @model keyword at the top of the .cshtml file.

Comment: That's what's I'm getting hung up on. The view specifies @model ArticlesLandingLightModel. I'm fairly new to this project there has to be some sort of weird mapping going on somewhere. Just not really sure what to look for. I've not come across this sort of thing in an MVC site before. Appreciate your comments though

Comment: It's probably a different view being rendered, or the view inherits a layout which in turn specifies that model type. Good luck!

Comment: You can also get this error if you forget to pass along the model to a Html.Partial() in your layout or page. Check that your model is not null.